# Blender 2.83 - Hair particles with big diameter showing cuts in strands

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I am trying to make an anemone like model and want to render the tentacles as hair particles. So I need to increase the root diameter quite a lot. It is actually a few meters now (which of course is not realistic), but I don't think that adds to the problem.

In the render preview you can see cuts in some hair strands and I wonder why this happens.

[image]

For the shader I do not use Hair BDSF but a simple custom one for now. I tried to adjust render steps, segments, render path settings, shader .. but nothing has an effect on the issue. I'll append the file to fiddle with.

If you increase the render steps (Render Tab -> Path) to 5 and check the B-Spline option the result gets smoother, but then the strand will look like an elephant's trunk (more cuts) :-) like so:

[image]

The interpolations just does not seem smooth. I forgot to check "Close Tips" for the screenshots, but this also does not have an effect on these cuts.

I could always make a few tentacle objects and use a particle group instead, but I wonder if is not possible to solve this using the standard hair system.

Happy if you have an idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you, it seems to have fixed the issue in my machine.
[image]

Change the Primitive to curve segments in Render Properties > Hair.

Comment: Oh my, yes it does on my machine too, great! I am happy with the result. I never really changed those parameters before, thanks a lot for pointing that out! Only drawback seems to be much longer rendertimes, but that's bcs. I can't render on GPU and my machine is old.

Comment: Try using the least amount of curve subdivisions you can get away with, cuz I literally just punched some random number in there, to see if that helped, no further testing. 
But unfortunately, that's how it goes, there's always a trade off between quality and render time..... I'm just glad it works! 
Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks again, I ended up with 4 Curve subdivisions and got a smooth enough result..

Comment: No problem, have fun!